# Content is not allowed in prolog. in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

In android studio, the project sync is successful. But when I try to build or run the project it shows the error 'Content is not allowed in prolog'. I tried invalidate caches but in vain. I also tried to clean and rebuild project but it didn't work.

Here is my gradle build log

> Task :app:processDebugResources
> [Fatal Error] aapt2-4.2.1-7147631.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@1b75aaee of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform
> Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@1b75aaee of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration1'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.2.1-7147631.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.2.1-7147631.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.2.1-7147631/aapt2-4.2.1-7147631.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the latest version of gradle classpath dependency

> classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"

I changed it to

> classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"

Magically, all errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

When you import your project on a different machine, and you have disabled in app gradle file `dependenciesInfo { includeInApk false includeInBundle false }`
Then most probably you will get

> Content is not allowed in prolog. error

Remove these two lines from app gradle, clean your cache and build the project. It will resolve the issue.